# Seating 5 distinct men, women, and a dog around a circular table such that no two people of the same gender are consecutive

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to offer a known erroneous solution to the titular question. It would be fantastic if someone could point out what went wrong. Of course, feel free to offer your own creative solutions.

It can be proved that no two people of the same gender can be seated next to the dog. We will proceed initially without the dog, using a 10-seat table. We seat 5 men around the table, leaving gaps between one man and the next. There are $5!$ ways to do this. Next, we seat the women around the table in the preexisting gaps, there are also $5!$ ways to do so. We must also account for rotation, thus there is $$\frac{(5!)^{2}}{10}$$ ways to seat the men and women around the table. The dog can be inserted in any of the 10 gaps between each person, thus we have a total of $$\frac{(5!)^{2}}{10} \cdot 10 = (5!)^2$$ ways to seat all of the entities.

Comment: Combinatorial questions about items in a circle are tricky. Are we looking only at relative positions around the table? If so put the dog in one of the 11 seats around the table as a marker. Make MW pairs with all men on the left (or right) $(2\cdot 5!$ ways), then arrange the 5 pairs around the table $(5!$ ways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given it is a circular table, when you are seating women first or men first, you need to fix one of the positions and make all arrangements relative to that (assuming rotational symmetry).

If so, there are only $4!$ ways to seat $5$ women leaving one seat in between each of them for men. Then there are $5!$ ways to seat men in those $5$ empty seats. Now you have $10$ places where you can seat the dog.

So total number of arrangements are $4! \times 5! \times 10 = 2 \times (5!)^2$.

Another way to look at this is to let the dog take the first seat as it wishes. Now we go clockwise seating women and men in alternate seats. There are $(5!)^2$ ways to do that starting with a woman as women can be arranged in $5!$ ways and so can be men. But we can also start with a man. So we have another $(5!)^2$ arrangements - in total $2 \times (5!)^2$ arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that your original placing of the men has $10\times 4!$ possibilities.